# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException not showing column names in exception message

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jdbc

I'm using `JPA` with `Hibernate` and `MySQL`.

What I want is to catch **MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException** to get `unicity` constraint violations, and show which field was violated, getting the field names from the exception message, but it only shows me some weird hash instead of the column name.

My mapping is just some default **mapping**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myentity")
public class SomeEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, name = "somefield")
    @NotNull
    private String somefield;
}
```

The **exception** is

```
caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '54533355000175' for key 'UK_bg2tfjjhyqxens7cw8a4uhscw'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
```

The message I want to **parse** is:

```
Duplicate entry '54533355000175' for key 'UK_bg2tfjjhyqxens7cw8a4uhscw'
```

How can I translate this key `'UK_bg2tfjjhyqxens7cw8a4uhscw'` to the proper column `somefield` name? Is there some configuration I can add somewhere to accomplish this?

Comment: A FK is given a name when creating the FK and you do not provide a name. One option is to simply provide the FK "name" in your JPA mapping, and then create the schema. Alternatively you'd need to go to MySQL and find the FK names that were generated, and what column(s) they map to

Comment: What you mean by FK? The table has no FKs.

Comment: sorry, meant to say constraint (of which a FK is but one type). Perhaps your unique constraint in that class

Comment: Could you provide some example on how to do it?

Comment: `@Table` has "uniqueConstraints" and with that you can specify the constraint name.

Comment: @BillyFrost you're right. Since you didn't post an answer, I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it like [@Billy Frost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3973283/billy-frost) pointed out, using the `@Table` `uniqueConstraints` annontation field.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myentity", uniqueConstraints = { 
  @UniqueConstraint(name = "theNameIWant"), columnNames={"somefield"},
  ... other constraints ...
}
)
public class SomeEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, name = "somefield")
    @NotNull
    private String somefield;
}
```